Running two instances of Tailscale simultaneously
I’m looking to find out if it’s possible to run two instances of Tailscale simultaneously on the same device, and if so, how to set it up.
The idea is to configure multiple Tailscale exit nodes, each with a different IP address (using Mullvad VPN), and then assign each Tailscale network to a separate OBS instance on my machine. This way, I could effectively route traffic from different OBS instances through distinct Tailscale networks.
Does anyone know if this is achievable? Any tips or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help!

As far as I understand currently the support is limited switching to different tailnets on a single system.
As per discussions on updates on Dec 2024:

tailscale forum
GitHub Issue 183

Refer: Quickly Switching tailscale account article here.
You could track various discussions on the GitHub issue to see if any solution will work for you.
But as far as I can understand you will need to take care of any networking issue manually as you could easily break basic system networking and have a broken system with limited/no network connectivity.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
